# Pydot Cluster positioning

Tags: python, pydot

If have two clusters containing a hierarchy of other clusters. All very cool!

I want to place the two clusters vertically. Although other posts suggest how to place nodes (not clusters) vertically I am unable to get this to work for a cluster.

The size parameter isn't working for me, but in any case this seems the wrong answer because my python program is to generically set out a class of graphs that may be any size. I just want the two clusters on top of the other and the size should be whatever.

A simple example would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
I have two independent clusters each containing a heirarchy of subclusters and portrayed as rectangles.
If I add the two clusters to my graph they appear left to right but I want them one on top of the other.
To get them in a vertical orientation if I add a node to each cluster. they can be made invisible in the style modifier but I used the nodes as labels. By adding an edge between the two nodes the two clusters orient themselves in the most sensible way to minimise the edge length and they get rearranged vertically.

In the below example I create two more enclosing blocks which may not be necessary since you could add a node to cluster1 and the other in cluster2 however I found the enclosing blocks it made my diagram neater.

So for example;

```
#Assume cluster1 and cluser2 exist

#Create enclosing cluster box
enclosingBlock1=pydot.Cluster('eb1', label='label1',shape='rectangle')
enclosingBlock1.add_subgraph(cluster1)

# Add node to enclosing cluster
node1=pydot.Node('D1',label='Diagram1')
enclosingBlock1.add_node(node1)

#Create second enclosing block
enclosingBlock2=pydot.Cluster('eb2', label='label2',shape='rectangle')
enclosingBlock2.add_subgraph(cluster2)
# Add the node and create the joining edge
node2=pydot.Node('D2',label='Diagram2')
enclosingBlock2.add_node(node2)
edge = pydot.Edge(node1,node2)

graph.add_subgraph(enclosingBlock1)
graph.add_subgraph(enclosingBlock2)
graph.add_edge(edge)
graph.write('xmlSQL.png',prog = 'dot',format = 'png')
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for the problem of ranking clusters is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329126/1959808). It involves setting [`constraint = false`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint) on certain edges, so that `dot` will ignore them when ranking the nodes.

In the linked post the approach is described heuristically. The method that worked for me when generating [control-flow graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) automatically, is to set a false `constraint` on backward edges.

In control-flow graphs, backward edges are those that return from the exit of a loop body to its entry. So, if your application involves such identifiable edges, then you can automate it, otherwise it can still be used as the guiding principle to select the edges manually.

If such identifiable edges are not known from a priori structural information about the problem, but you still want to automate the deconstraining of edges, then you can use the depth-first or breadth-first tree (your choice) to select a subset of edges as backward.