# Layering in Graphviz using Dot Language

Tags: data-visualization, graphviz, dot

I am working on a dot file to present the layering for nodes.

The figure I have is this one. 
(sorry, I do not have enough reputation to post images..)
http://www.flickr.com/photos/40328682@N03/8473003861/in/photostream/lightbox/

However, I want the trees (blue nodes) not to be compressed and occupy only one layer for each tree. I draw an example by adding invisible nodes and more edges, like this: 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/40328682@N03/8474093000/in/photostream/lightbox/

I tried $ rank = same $ to make the yellow node and blue node (top one) on the same level, but I cannot add more layers without inserting invisible nodes.

Is there any way I can add more layers between different ranks **without adding invisible nodes**? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no connections between sub-graphs, then there is no way to control their positioning. Using `rank=same` is a common approach in the legend on the left along with the invisible nodes to force structure into the layout.

If you simply need to add a minimum amount of space between two nodes, then you can use the `minlen =` attribute on a hidden edge to force the required separation. This is also explained in [subgraph cluster ranking in dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499032/subgraph-cluster-ranking-in-dot/3329126#3329126).

This is demonstrated in:

```
digraph {
    node [label = ""];

    A; B; C; D;
    E [style = invis];

    {   node [shape = box, label = ""];

        1 -> 2;
        3 -> { 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; }; 5 -> 13; 7 -> 14; 10 -> 15; 12 -> { 16; 17; }; 16 -> 18;
        19 -> { 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40; 41; }; 35 -> 42; 36 -> 43; 40 -> { 45; 46; }; 41 -> 44;
        20 -> { 21; 22; 23};
    }

    {   edge [weight = 10];
        A -> B [minlen = 2];
        B -> C [minlen = 3];
        C -> D [minlen = 3];
        D -> E [style = invis];
    }

    {   rank = same; A -> 1; }
    {   rank = same; B -> 3; }
    {   rank = same; C -> 19; }
    {   rank = same; D -> 20; }
}
```

The last tree (referenced from `D` would fall under the ellipses on the left without the hidden `E`. If this is not acceptable, then a hidden edge from one of the nodes in the tree above needs to be connected to node `20`.

The spacing between the ellipses can be adjusted with the `minlen =` attributes.