# DOT: How to place clusters at same level without ranking equally the nodes in those clusters?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have below DOT code. It describes five subgraphs (clusters). I am happy with the rendering of the two lower clusters and also with the relative position of the clusters (three on the top at the same level and two at the bottom in the respective order). However, I would like that the nods in the upper three clusters are ranked according to the internal relationships of their nodes, similar to what I get in the lower two clusters (As you see, the nodes in the upper clusters are rendered all in a single row despite the presence of hidden edges between some of  them).

I understand that the reason they are not is the `rank=same;` command. However, if I remove that I am losing the positioning of the clusters. I tried a couple of variants using different combinations of the commands and additional ones such as `clusterrank=local;`, but the result below stayed the closest. Also [subgraph cluster ranking in dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499032/subgraph-cluster-ranking-in-dot) did not get me what I want.

```
digraph G {

    splines=line;
    size=1;
    ranksep=2;
    newrank=true;
    rankdir=BT

    subgraph cluster_z {
      label="Z";
      rank=same;

      "ZSF" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZTA" [fillcolor = red]; 
      "ZSS" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZIN" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZOW" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZNT" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZSS" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZCE" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZAY" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZNT" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZTA" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZTA" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZST" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZTO" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZON" [fillcolor = red];
      "ZPP" [fillcolor = red];
      "TNT" [fillcolor = red];
      "TCE" [fillcolor = red];
      "TNT" [fillcolor = red];


      "ZNT" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZSF" [style=invis]
      "ZSF" -> "ZNT" [style=invis]

      "ZIN" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZON" [style=invis]
      "ZON" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZSF" [style=invis]
      "ZSF" -> "ZNT" [style=invis]
      "ZNT" -> "ZIN" [style=invis]

      "ZPP" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZSF" [style=invis]
      "ZSF" -> "ZPP" [style=invis]

      "ZSF" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZSF" [style=invis]

      "ZOW" -> "ZSS" [style=invis]
      "ZSS" -> "ZOW" [style=invis]

      "ZAY" -> "ZCE" [style=invis]
      "ZCE" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZAY" [style=invis]

      "ZSF" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZAY" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZSF" [style=invis]

      "ZAY" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZCE" [style=invis]
      "ZCE" -> "ZTA" [style=invis]
      "ZTA" -> "ZSF" [style=invis]
      "ZSF" -> "ZAY" [style=invis]

    }

    subgraph cluster_y {
      rank=same;
      label="Y";

      "YCY" [fillcolor = blue];
      "YES" [fillcolor = blue];
    }

    subgraph cluster_w {

      rank=same;
      label="W";

      "WER" [fillcolor = green];
      "WRT" [fillcolor = green];
    }

    subgraph cluster_o {

      label="O";
      "OOL" [fillcolor = white];
      "OOL" [fillcolor = white];
      "OIT" [fillcolor = white];
      "ONT" [fillcolor = white];
      "OGE" [fillcolor = white];
      "OTA" [fillcolor = white];
      "OTA" [fillcolor = white];
      "OTS" [fillcolor = white];
      "OTS" [fillcolor = white];
      "OCE" [fillcolor = white];
      "ORT" [fillcolor = white];
      "ORT" [fillcolor = white];
      "OON" [fillcolor = white];
      "OCT" [fillcolor = white];
      "OOL" [fillcolor = white];
      "OTO" [fillcolor = white];
      "OPE" [fillcolor = white];
      "OPY" [fillcolor = white];

      "OIT" -> "ORT" [style=invis]
      "ORT" -> "OON" [style=invis]
      "OON" -> "OPE" [style=invis]
      "OPE" -> "OIT" [style=invis]

      "OON" -> "OPE" [style=invis]
      "OPE" -> "OON" [style=invis]

      "OOL" -> "OOL" [style=invis]
      "OOL" -> "OOL" [style=invis]

      "OCE" -> "OON" [style=invis]
      "OON" -> "OCE" [style=invis]

      "OTA" -> "OON" [style=invis]
      "OON" -> "OTA" [style=invis]

      "OIT" -> "OTA" [style=invis]
      "OTA" -> "ORT" [style=invis]
      "ORT" -> "ORT" [style=invis]
      "ORT" -> "OON" [style=invis]
      "OON" -> "OIT" [style=invis]

      "OIT" -> "OTA" [style=invis]
      "OTA" -> "OTS" [style=invis]
      "OTS" -> "OON" [style=invis]
      "OON" -> "OPE" [style=invis]
      "OPE" -> "OIT" [style=invis]

    }

    subgraph cluster_e {
      label="E";

      "EUT" [fillcolor = grey];
      "EON" [fillcolor = grey];
      "ERT" [fillcolor = grey];
      "ERT" [fillcolor = grey];
      "EST" [fillcolor = grey];
      "EON" [fillcolor = grey];
      "EER" [fillcolor = grey];
      "ERE" [fillcolor = grey];
      "ETO" [fillcolor = grey];

    }

    "OIT" -> "ZSF";
    "ORT" -> "ZSF";
    "OON" -> "ZSF";
    "OPE" -> "ZSF";
    "EON" -> "ZSF";
    "EER" -> "ZSF";

    "OON" -> "ZTA";
    "OPE" -> "ZTA";
    "EER" -> "ZTA";

    "OOL" -> "ZSS";
    "OOL" -> "ZSS";

    "OGE" -> "ZIN";
    "EON" -> "ZIN";

    "OOL" -> "ZOW";

    "OTS" -> "ZNT";

    "OCT" -> "ZSS";

    "OCE" -> "ZCE";
    "OON" -> "ZCE";

    "OTA" -> "ZAY";
    "OON" -> "ZAY";

    "OIT" -> "ZNT";
    "EON" -> "ZNT";

    "OIT" -> "ZTA";
    "OTA" -> "ZTA";
    "ORT" -> "ZTA";
    "ORT" -> "ZTA";
    "OON" -> "ZTA";
    "EON" -> "ZTA";
    "ERE" -> "ZTA";

    "OIT" -> "ZTA";
    "OTA" -> "ZTA";
    "OTS" -> "ZTA";
    "OON" -> "ZTA";
    "OPE" -> "ZTA";
    "EON" -> "ZTA";
    "ERE" -> "ZTA";

    "OOL" -> "ZST";

    "OTO" -> "ZTO";

    "ONT" -> "ZON";
    "EON" -> "ZON";

    "OPY" -> "ZPP";
    "EER" -> "ZPP";


  { rank=same; "ZSF"; "YCY"; "WER" }
  { rank=same; "OPY"; "EER"}


}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You probably need to describe a bit more in detail, best with a reduced sample, what you mean with _I would like that the nods in the upper three clusters are ranked according to the internal relationships of their nodes, similar to what I get in the lower two clusters_. Your code is quite complicated and takes a lot of time to understand, so it would be helpful to understand exactly where you want to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all the duplicate lines, invisible edges, and colour attributes.

I then gave it some colour to make visible what I've done.

The source is like this:

```
digraph G {

newrank=true;
rankdir=BT;
ranksep=2;
splines=line;

subgraph cluster_z {
    label="Z";
    "TCE";
    "TNT";
    "ZAY";
    "ZCE";
    "ZIN";
    "ZNT";
    "ZON";
    "ZOW";
    "ZPP";
    "ZSF";
    "ZSS";
    "ZST";
    "ZTA";
    "ZTO";
}

subgraph cluster_y {
    rank=same;
    label="Y";
    "YCY";
    "YES";
}

subgraph cluster_w {
    rank=same;
    label="W";
    "WER";
    "WRT";
}

subgraph cluster_o {
    label="O";
    "OCE";
    "OCT";
    "OGE";
    "OIT";
    "ONT";
    "OOL";
    "OON";
    "OPE";
    "OPY";
    "ORT";
    "OTA";
    "OTO";
    "OTS";
}

subgraph cluster_e {
  label="E";
  "EUT";
  "ERT";
  "EST";
  "EON";
  "EER";
  "ERE";
  "ETO";
}

/* All the edges */
"EER" -> "ZPP";
"EER" -> "ZSF";
"EER" -> "ZTA";
"EON" -> "ZIN";
"EON" -> "ZNT";
"EON" -> "ZON";
"EON" -> "ZSF";
"EON" -> "ZTA";
"ERE" -> "ZTA";
"OCE" -> "ZCE";
"OCT" -> "ZSS";
"OGE" -> "ZIN";
"OIT" -> "ZNT";
"OIT" -> "ZSF";
"OIT" -> "ZTA";
"ONT" -> "ZON";
"OOL" -> "ZOW";
"OOL" -> "ZSS";
"OOL" -> "ZST";
"OON" -> "ZAY";
"OON" -> "ZCE";
"OON" -> "ZSF";
"OON" -> "ZTA";
"OPE" -> "ZSF";
"OPE" -> "ZTA";
"OPY" -> "ZPP";
"ORT" -> "ZSF";
"ORT" -> "ZTA";
"OTA" -> "ZAY";
"OTA" -> "ZTA";
"OTO" -> "ZTO";
"OTS" -> "ZNT";
"OTS" -> "ZTA";

/* 15 nodes from cluster_z and cluster_y and cluster_w */
{ rank = same;
    "TCE" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "TNT" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "WER" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "WRT" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "YCY" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "YES" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZAY" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZCE" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZIN" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZON" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZOW" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZPP" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZSS" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZST" [style = filled; color = green;]
    "ZTO" [style = filled; color = green;]
}

/* 10 nodes from cluster_o and cluster_e */
{ rank = same;
    "OCE" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "OCT" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "OGE" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "ONT" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "OOL" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "OPY" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "OTO" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "EON" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "EER" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
    "ERE" [style = filled; color = yellow;]
}

/* Gives cluster_z 2 rows of nodes. */
"ZSF" -> "ZTO" [color = red];

/* Gives cluster_o 4 rows of nodes. */
"OIT" -> "OON" -> "OPE" -> "ORT" [color = red];

}
```

while the image looks like this:
[image]
so you can fiddle with it as you like.

Comment: Thanks. Any improvements you'd like?

Comment: I first need to see how it behaves for my larger graph. I have come up with a different solution that places the 3/2 of the 5 subgraphs on the two levels in subgraphs each and introduces further invisible nodes/edges to get the their placement ritght. There has been a certain reason for those invisible nodes, but your solution perfectly solves the described problem.

Comment: Ah. I was wondering what all those invisible nodes and edges were for. Anyway, what I did for this example was to distinguish between nodes with 3 or more arrowheads and nodes with two or less arrowheads. Hope that helps.